# Finding id of an array of object and dispay it's data dynamically on the page using url parameters in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects :

```
let eventObj = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Peter",
    title: "Lorem",
    day: "saturday",
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Peter",
    title: "Lorem",
    day: "saturday",
}
```

and I am making a `function` that gets the `id`

```
export const getEvent = id => {
  return eventObj[id];
}
```

Then in my `App.js` file I am taking that function that gives me the details of the event

```
<Main  Main={getEvent(0)} />
```

and taking what is in that component in my `Main.js` file

```
const {Main} = this.props;
```

My main problem is that I can't figure out how to show my data dynamically. I don't know what to do with my

```
<Main  Main={getEvent(0)} />
```

because it only shows my first object.

Comment: What does the 0 in `getEvent(0)` represent? What would you want instead of it?

Comment: There are going to be different events on my page with unique ids. When I click on one of the events I want to take the id from that event and it will show in the url and then take that url which can be for example id=2. Then take id nr 2 which is going to display the date from my object

Comment: Which version of the Router are you using?

Comment: import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the route to your `SomeComponent` component is

```
<Route path="/somecomponent/:id" component={SomeComponent} />
```

So, you navigate to id by passing the id route parameter, e.g. `https://yourhost.com/somecomponent/3`.

Within your `SomeComponent` component, you can access the `id` parameter at:

```js
this.props.match.params.id
```

And you can do something like:

```
const eventData = getEvent(this.props.match.params.id);
<Main Main={eventData} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to show all `eventObjects` from that array with your `<Main ... />` component, then you can map over that array and show.

```
    let eventObj = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Peter",
    title: "Lorem",
    day: "saturday",
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Peter",
    title: "Lorem",
    day: "saturday",
}

const renderEvents = eventObj.map((event) => <Main Main={getEvent(event.id)} />);

<div>
  {renderEvents}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only showing your first object because you are only asking for your first object.

Just like `getEvent(1)` would always return the second object.

To get the object dynamically your method depends on what you are trying to do.

You can pass the desired id into it (for example by making a variable out of an input and passing it to the function `getEvent(myVar)`

Or you could map over all objects an return them all using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).